# How to count the number of times an array value is repeated in another array element using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have a piece of XML data as follows:

```
<scientist>
  <name>Emmy Noether&amp;Amalie</name>
</scientist>

<day>
  <date>03-23-2015</date>
  <wiki>Emmy Noether&amp;Amalie was an influential German mathematician known for her groundbreaking contributions to abstract algebra and theoretical physics. Emmy Noether&amp;Amalie was born on 23 March 1882, the first of four children. In 1932 Emmy Noether and Emil Artin received the Ackermann–Teubner Memorial Award for their contributions to mathematics.</wiki>
</day>
```

My question is how to count the number of times the `name` value of `scientist` (i.e. `Emmy Noether&amp;Amalie`) is repeated in the `wiki` element of the above XML element? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SimpleXML to parse the XML ?

If you isolated all the wiki tags, you can count the number of name tag occurences using substr_count function

Comment: yes exactly, something like `file='file.xml';
$xml=file_get_contents($file);
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml),TRUE);`